# How to change a website image with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, greasemonkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change a website image with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846835/how-to-change-a-website-image-with-javascript)

I'm working with my first greasemonkey script.

And its for a website that have a logo, i want to change the image to a image i have created, and i wonder how i do this?

like use javascript to edit the current html document and replace the image.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** *The image is inside a  tag, the image i want to change/replace is in this code:*

```
<img class="fb_logo img" src="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yp/r/kk8dc2UJYJ4.png" alt="Facebook logo" width="170" height="36">
```