# Replace line in css file, using Greasemonkey

Tags: css, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a Greasemonkey script that replaces one line of a `.css` file.

The original line from `all.css` is

```
#header {
    background: transparent url('img/bg-graph-top.png?v=7e4ce14d05fb') no-repeat 50% -25px;
}
```

I'd like to replace it with

```
#header {
    background: transparent url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Dummy_flag.png') no-repeat 50% -25px;
}
```

---

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854437/9072294 I tried to write my very first userscript like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            swap
// @include         http://tex.stackexchange.com/*
// @include         https://tex.stackexchange.com/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var desiredImage    = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Dummy_flag.png";

//--- Straight image swap:
$('img/bg-graph-top.png?v=7e4ce14d05fb').attr ('src', desiredImage);

/*--- Replace the link's -- with the logo as a background -- contents with just a plain image.
    Since this image is transparent, clear the old BG image.
    Also constrain the new img to its container. 
*/
$('#header all').css ('background-', 'none')
                .append ('<url>').find ('img/bg-graph-top.png?v=7e4ce14d05fb')  .attr ('src', desiredImage).css ();
```

However the image is not changing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change a background image, not an `<img>` tag, like that other answer.

For such things, just use CSS overrides.

Here's what it looks like in a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _TeX SE, Swap header background
// @match       *://tex.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `
    #header {
        background: transparent url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Dummy_flag.png') no-repeat 50% -25px !important;
    }
` );
```

Note the `!important` flag.

Also, `@run-at  document-start` may complicate things if your script does any [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) manipulation.

Anyway, **for pure CSS changes, like this one, you are better off using [the Stylish extension](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stylish/info).**  It's less fuss and performs better

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you very much! (I cannot yet upvote, will do it as soon as I reach 15 reputation)

Comment: And thank you for the suggestion of the `stylish` extension. You are absolutely correct, that this would be easier to use. However I am really glad you provided a Greasemonkey solution, as this extension is anyway installed for various other purposes.

Comment: Those who stumble upon this: be wary, the stylish extension seems to be laced with maleware now!  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/